# Откуда берутся прокси

Tags: прокси, php

Возникла надобность написать чеккер прокси. Есть [такие](http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru) сайты. Они я так понимаю чекают прокси раз в день. Но где они берут прокси?

Answer (score 1):

Этот сайт просто, как я понял, проверяет валидность прокси. Если тебя интересует, откуда они берут списки проксей, то их просто набивают админы, а те, в свою очередь берут их на тематических форумах. Можно, конечно, сканить подряд все хосты на прокси..но неблагодарное это дело.

Comment: То есть все хосты? 

А на тематических  форумах выкладывают люди  которые берут прокси с таких сайтов

Comment: то-есть берем список адресов определенной страны и проходимся по всем ним - пингуем, если пингуется проверяем известные порты для прокси (пытаемся подключится через сокеты). Потом если очень надо проверяем все 65535 портов на соотвтствие прокси серверу. И таким образом составляем список. Но понятное дело, что это очень неблагодарное дело и скорее всего те прокси умрут до того как вы соберете список сами. Поэтому там работает несколько сотен серверов которые это все проверяют и если выявился прокси то они его в базу заносят. Если он пропадает сканируют его остальные порты. В общем замкнутыйкру

Comment: Ну да, легче граббер написать который запускается кроном и собирает прокси. А потом заустить кроном проверку прокси

Comment: Но сколько скрипту придётся работать